# How To create Sequence in Oracle Developer 6i

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am trying to make a simple interface for a small table. I am trying to make the it auto generated. The creation of the table as the following:

```
create table Buyer_Entery_Table 
(
serial_number number(6) not null  customers_seq,
good_name varchar2(300),
employee_name  varchar2(400),
Quantity number(6),
value number(10),
entry_number number(6),
outer_number number(6),
today date, 
department_name varchar2(300),
notes varchar2(400) 
);
```

I created a sequence as well as the following :

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

In the form builder, I add a trigger in the block level. The trigger is PRE-INSERT. 
I used This code :

```
declare
 v_no number;
  Begin
    select customers_seq.nextval into v_no from Dual;
        :Buyer_Entery_table.serial_number := v_no;
  end;
```

I have tried to compile. I have the following error.

ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17069], [101534824], [], [], [], [], [], []

Any idea what mistakes I have done ?

Comment: make your tag appropriate

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to bug in forms 6i.You need [Patch 17](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=patch&id=17) to resolve it.

Kindly connect to metalink.oracle.com and go to the patch-section for downloading  the patch 17 [link here](https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=patch&id=17) and install it.

If you don't have metalink account you can create a metalink account.

Go in metalink on the registration and fill out the form with the data of your software license

Refer [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/532473?start=0&tstart=0) for more information

The problem is using dual in oracle forms As a workaround you can try to create a plsql procedure in database

```
create or replace procedure pr_increment_sequence(p_increment OUT NUMBER) is
begin
select customers_seq.nextval into p_increment from Dual;
end pr_increment_sequence;
```

and the below code in Oracle forms

```
 declare
 v_no number;
 Begin
 pr_increment_sequence(v_no);
    :Buyer_Entery_table.serial_number := v_no;
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a table dual with dummy column name..
and insert some value thats it..your work is done
SYNTAX
create table dual(dummy varchar2(10));
insert into dual('a');